# Expression Engine 3 - Entries Tag - page_uri empty

Tags: php, uri, expressionengine, expressionengine3

**EDIT**:

I'm rewriting my question in order to explain everything properly, so here goes.

We were using ExpressionEngine `3.1.0`, and have recently updated to `3.1.2` - pretty much as soon as it was available to do so.

Since doing so we've run into a genuine error with the `{page_uri}` or `{page_url}` tag. The `pages module` is installed and we've added a news item that utilises it. All fields required are filled in, so there is no error there.

The problem we are getting is that absolutely no content is being output in the `{page_uri}` or `{page_url}` tags and cannot find a reason for it. Our loop, including testing code, is below:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="news" limit="1" dynamic="no"}
    (1){url_title_path='news'}(2){page_uri}(3){page_url}(4){permalink}
    <div class="item-double news">
        <div class="social-wall-logo"><img src="/assets/local/img/news_icon.png" alt="News" /></div>
        <div class="social-wall-heading">News</div>
        <div class="social-wall-content">{title}</div>
        <div class="social-wall-view-more"><a href="{url_title_path='news'}{page_uri}{page_url}"><img src="/assets/local/img/view_btn.png" alt="View" /></a></div>
    </div>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

The channel is correct, `{url_title_path}` does output the title but this isn't the correct way of outputting URIs and all other tags (like `{title}`) output what we've entered.

We've spent about 2 hours on this bug and cannot think of nor find anything that we've done wrong. But if you can see something that looks amiss please, please say so, haha!

Thank you for looking,

Andy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Derek from EllisLab has commented on the bug report and stated that this:

> In `/system/ee/legacy/core/Config.php` change `line 47` from:
>
> `$this->config = get_config();`  to:
>
> `$this->config =& get_config();`

https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/21558/pages-page_uri-doesnt-work

I've just tried it and it works fine now. Should be a part of an upcoming release, which I assume will be released in a couple of days if not sooner due to the nature of the issue.

Answer (score -1):

From [the documentation](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/channel/channel_entries.html#page-uri):

> If you have the Pages Module installed and if you have associated a static page with a channel entry (via the “Pages” section of the Publish tab), this is the page uri for the page.

Perhaps you have not met the requirements mentioned in the documentation?

If this doesn't solve your problem please update your question to elaborate on these settings...

Comment: Pretty sure we've done all that, basic EE things we do in day in day out :/ I'll check tomorrow when I'm back at the office

Comment: I've rewritten the question, hope this helps